# Programmatically reset tokenization state in Monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I created a `TokensProvider` to provide syntax highlighting to my custom language.
This works, but it only redraws when text is edited.

Problem is - My custom language depends on outside context that can change even if text does not. Thus I need to trigger syntax highlighting redraw even when text does not change.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging through `vscode` repo, looks like the following line works:

```
monaco.editor.getModel(url)._resetTokenizationState()
```

Unfortunately, this looks like an undocumented API that might break with future versions, so a public API will be nice.

Answer (score 0):

In monaco editor version 0.33.0 (perhaps prior) the method has been moved into the member object _tokenization of the TextModel. There you have to use

```
monaco.editor.getModel(url)._tokenization._resetTokenizationState()
```